# Get a Escape character in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping, delimiter

```
Select '"'||Address||'","'||zipcode||'"' from Address_table;
```

output:

```
"123 Main St Ave Apt 100","98765"   -- Good Data            
"312 Marco St Some Ave "Apt 3214"","76543" -- Bad Data
```

Desired Output:

```
"123 street Main Ave Apt 100","98765"    
"312 Marco St,Some Ave \"Apt 3214\"","76543"
```

I want to achieve this using SQL in Oracle. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use [REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm):

```
Select '"'||REPLACE(Address, '"', '\"')||'","'||zipcode||'"' from Address_table;
```